# Pandas best practice: remove column names?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm sorting a dataframe containing stock capitalisations from largest to smallest row-wise (I will compute the ratio of top 10 stocks vs the whole market as a proxy for concentration).

```
f = lambda x: pd.Series(x.sort_values(ascending=False, na_position='last').to_numpy(), index=stock_mv.columns)
stock_mv = stock_mv.apply(f, axis=1)
```

When I do this, however, the column names (tickers) no longer make sense. I read somewhere that you shouldn't delete column names or have them set to the same thing.

What is the best practice thing to do in this situation?

Thank you very much - I am very much a novice coder.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your problem right, you want to sort a dataframe row-wise. If that's the case, Try this:

```
stock_mv = stock_mv.sort_values(axis=1, ascending=False)
```

Comment: Thank you for answering... but that wasn't what I meant to ask. My code is correct. My question is - what should I do about defunct column names - in terms of best practice

Comment: What do you mean by defunct column names?

Comment: Data comes in with each column being a stock ticker and each row a date. Each cell is the market value on that date. Since I sort the dataframe row wise on every single row - the column names are meaningless - and potentially misleading